# How to login to Cloud 9 via API calls

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have a REST API in development on Cloud 9. When logged in vai a browser I can call my API methodss due to the expected cookie being set.

Now I am developing a mobile frontend, however I can't call the API as I am not logged in. Does anyone know if there is some header I can set to allow access?

There seems to be no information relating to this in any of their documentation or my Google-fu has failed!

Comment: I have tried basic auth with my user and password and that is ignored. For now I am just manually setting the cookie header - maybe this is the only supported way? I'm not a big fan of using cookies in an API!

Comment: Hi, could you send a message via https://c9.io/support describing your issue in more details?

Comment: Little bit slow - but I have now done so, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can make your running app public which removed the need for the
>   session cookie and the login screen. You can do so from the sharing
>   dialog (top right of the menu bar). There select public for
>   "Application".

Thanks to Cloud 9 support